# How to display corresponding value in a input field when a value is selected into another input field JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two input fields which are depends on each other. The value is coming as an **array of objects** from database. I want to auto fill the input field with the corresponding values when I select the value into one input field.

Here is the code I have tried. But I am still getting it as **[object,object]**. Where is my mistake? Any help would be appreciated.

```
if (serviceURL == "myURL") {
  var Data = '';

  $.get(serviceURL, function(response) {
    var Data = $.map(response, function(value, index) {
      data = value;
      return[value];
    })
  }).done(function() {
    $("#" + id).autocomplete({
      source: Data,
      minLength: 0;
      scroll: true
    }).focus(function() {
      $(this).autocomplete("search", "");
    });
  });

   $("#1stIpId").change(function() {
    var val = $this.val();
    $.each(Data, function(key, value) {
      if (val == key)
        $("#2ndIpId").val(value);
    })
  });
}
```

Please help.

Comment: could you provide a running snippet ? what i am seeing , i think the "value" contains objects and you are setting the val directly to "value" . you should try to console the value of "value"

Comment: `minLength: 0;` The `;` there will be causing a syntax error. Check the console

Comment: it was a typing mistake here...its actually `minLength:0,`

Comment: you can assign object as object[key/index]. It might help u. Provide an example which'll help us to help you out.